# Pairwise Distance Distribution on a Flat Torus

Tags: probability, geometry

I'm currently trying to work out the following.

Given two uniformly distributed random variables on the unit flat torus (i.e. $[0,1]^2$ which wraps around), what is the probability that their distance is less than some real number $r$? Further I will need the p.d.f, but this is just differentiating. Also if there's a better name for this I'd love to know it!

I've got the following:
If $0\leq r \leq 0.5$, then $P(d(X,Y)<r) = \pi r^2$, so the p.d.f is $f_{d(X,Y)}(r)=2\pi r$.

If $r\geq\sqrt{2}/2$, the c.d.f. is $1$.

If $0.5<r<\sqrt{2}/2$, I think the c.d.f is $\pi r^2$ minus the overlap of the circle around a point when the area of that circle wraps round the torus, something like this:

[image: Area of overlap]

Now I get this area to be $8r\arccos\left(\frac{1}{2r}\right)-2\sqrt{r^2-\frac{1}{4}}$, which differentiates to $$
8\arccos\left(\frac{1}{2r}\right)-\frac{8}{r\sqrt{4-r}}+\frac{2r}{\sqrt{r^2-\frac{1}{4}}}
$$

For the p.d.f. However, this has a singularity at $r=1/2$, whereas it should be $\pi$ since that's where the p.d.f for $r<0.5$ ends up.

Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Comment: (deleted previous comment) I found one error you made; the term should be $8r^2\arccos\left(\frac{1}{2r}\right)$ (square $r$).

Comment: I think you also used the wrong derivative for $\arccos$. You should have an $r^2$ in the radical there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is not quite correct. Actually, by translation invariance, you can always fix one point to be the origin (up to a lattice translation).
Your problem thus becomes finding the distance distribution of a uniformly distributed point on a square of unit side length with respect to the center of the square.

You are correct for the cdf for $r<1/2$ and $r>\sqrt2/2$, but not for the remaining interval. The correct area is rather the area of the intersection of the disk of radius $r$ and the square. To find it, decompose it into circular wedges and triangles. Your formula therefore changes to:
$$
F_<(r) = \sqrt{4r^2-1}+r^2(\pi-4\arccos(1/2r))
$$
so the total cdf is:
$$
F_<(r) = 
\begin{cases}
\pi r^2 & r \leq \frac12 \\
\sqrt{4r^2-1}+r^2(\pi-4\arccos(1/2r)) & r\geq\frac12
\end{cases}
$$
and you can check that $F_<(\sqrt2/2)=1$, and by differentiation you get the pdf:
$$
f(r) = 
\begin{cases}
2\pi r & r \leq \frac12 \\
2r(\pi-4\arccos(1/2r)) & r\geq\frac12
\end{cases}
$$
It's actually faster to get the pdf as it's just the length of the remaining circle arc inside the square (the red dotted lines in your figure, the $2\pi r$ is the length of the total circle and $8r\arccos(1/2r)$ is the length of the blue dotted circle arcs).

Hope this helps.